# AWS CloudWatch State Change rule and schedule

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloudwatch-alarms

I have a CloudWatch alarm for state change with the following code:

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.ec2"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "EC2 Instance State-change Notification"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "state": [
      "shutting-down",
      "stopping"
    ]
  }
}
```

It is working fine, but it also triggers events for AWS Instance Scheduler. Is there any way to prevent scheduled state changes from triggering this alarm? I googled for it, but no success.